# Access a function variable within an object from outside

Tags: php, oop

Following this structure:

```
class MyClass(){
   var prop;

   function myfunc(){
      $variable = 'value';
   }
}

$obj = new MyClass;
```

Is there a way i can access '$variable' from outside without a return?

I can get a property like this:

```
$obj -> prop;
```

but i can't access the '$variable' like this:

```
$obj -> variable;
```

Comment: Variable does not exist in your class, exists just in your method. You need to declare variables in class. And you should declare variable using access speciffiers: 
protected $variable;

Comment: @M.I. , so i just have to make it a property ? there is no way i can access it just like that?

Comment: The use of `var` to declare class properties has not been used for years [Take a quick glimps at the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and find a more up to date tutorial

Comment: @RiggsFolly , uhm .. ok , good to know , should i use public/private/protected ?

Comment: Yes..you need to make it property to use it in a class, inside the class itself you can access it with $this->variable. Also check static variables, that may be closer from what you are looking for, and with static you won't need to make a new instance of the class.

Comment: @Petru Lebada, $obj -> my_variable out the class, always return the initial value, but if you want to modify really you will modify it in the __construct

Comment: @bfahmi Why are you telling me?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, sorry :/

Comment: @Petru Check some basic OOP, set and get methods, access specifiers, static classes and variables. You will find plenty of information about this topics.

Comment: @M.I. , i did read those tutorials , i just couldn't find a concrete answer if i can do that in a way or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyClass(){
   public prop;
   public variable;    

   function myfunc(){
      $this->variable = 'value';
   }
}
```

using var inside the class is not recommended. instead of that you can use **public**

```
$obj -> variable; now you can access this from out side the class scope
```

Comment: I agree.. here and there syntax error. Created a working copy https://gist.github.com/pssubashps/a48b06b3f421563d2b6b0b0bac78ce80

Answer (score 1):

To access your variable like

```
$obj -> variable;
```

You need to make like this:

```
class MyClass(){
   var prop;
   var variable;    

   function myfunc(){
      $this->variable = 'value';
   }
}
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that `var $variable;` is the same as `public $variable;`. And not something we want to have normally as it can be modified by everyone ;-/